# Who do square brackets followed by braces mean inside a class method mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand this code? What do brackets [] mean after   definition or dictionary? (See line start with cert_verify))

I've run the google. Lots and lots. Apologize my not so good english.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import requests.adapters
from exchangelib.protocol import BaseProtocol

class RootCAAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    # An HTTP adapter that uses a custom root CA certificate at a hard coded location
    def cert_verify(self, conn, url, verify, cert):
        cert_file = {
            'example.com': '/path/to/example.com.crt',
            'mail.internal': '/path/to/mail.internal.crt',
        }[urlparse(url).hostname]
        super(RootCAAdapter, self).cert_verify(conn=conn, url=url, verify=cert_file, cert=cert)

# Tell exchangelib to use this adapter class instead of the default
BaseProtocol.HTTP_ADAPTER_CLS = RootCAAdapter
```

Comment: The same thing square-brackets always mean when applied to a `dict` object. So, do you understand: `d = {'foo':1, 'bar':2}; x = d['foo']`? Basically, this is an example of over-complicated code, the author chose to create a dict object with two key-value pairs to act as a "switch", however, a simple if-else would have been easier to read and understand, and less inefficient.

Comment: yes it is not so easy to know. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looking up the dictionary previously defined. I.e.

```
>>> result = {'a':1234, 'b':'hello'}['a']
>>> print(result)
1234
>>> result = {'a':1234, 'b':'hello'}['b']
>>> print(result)
hello
```

Keep on running with the google. Or duckduckgo.